# Catching "Access denied" error when setting an environment variable using subprocess.call

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, method-call

I was attempting to set an environment variable and it failed due to access denied, however, the try-except block did not catch this as an error. I could catch the exit code myself and then check if the exit code is different than 0, but I was hoping a more pythonic way is possible.

This is what I have tried so perform:

```
try:
    exit_code = subprocess.call(["SETX", "-m", "ENV_VAR", "Test"])
    print 'exit_code: {}'.format(exit_code)  # for debugging purposes
except Exception:
    raise Exception("Could not set environment variable")
```

And this was the result:

```
ERROR: Access to the registry path is denied.
exit_code: 1

Process finished with exit code 0
```

As you can see, the exit code that is being returned from subprocess.call is 1, indicating a failure, however,  the entire Python process is exiting with exit code 0 and "raise Exception" is never called.

What would be the best way to solve it?

Comment: Worth mentioning: I am aware that using "except Exception" is bad practice, but this was just an example to show the problem I am facing, and since I could not determine the exact type of error/exception that is being raised from subprocess.call in such a case.

Comment: You should use subprocess.check_call or subprocess.check_output instead and handle CalledProcessError exception. Link: https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#

Comment: @AlexK. Perfect, just what I needed. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Alex K.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5372300/alex-k) for pointing out the correct usage. The fixed code:

```
try:
    subprocess.check_call(["SETX", "-m", "ENV_VAR", "Test"])
except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
    raise Exception("Could not set environment variable")
```

Comment: I would advise rising the same error that you get so that you can see actual error message instead of "Could not set environment variable" in all cases. Or at least print/log/write it somewhere - it could save some time when debugging.